# Making a url request session returns empty while postman returns data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, urlsession

I'm trying to make an API call here using a post method, however I keep getting

> [[boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(144)]

and the data returned is an empty object  **{"finalResults":[]}**.

Tested the API using postman and the data returns safely.

This is my code:

```
var dict = Dictionary<String, String>()
    dict = [
        "queryText": query,
        "lat": "31.206865038834433",
        "long": "29.965068562105422",
        "pageToken": "",
    ]
    

    let url:URL = URL(string: apiEndPointURLString)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

   var postData = NSData()
    do{
        postData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) as NSData
    }catch {
        print("error serializing.......\n\n\n\n")
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("\(postData.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("text/html", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("json/application", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    request.httpBody = postData as Data

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        let dataString =  String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print(dataString ?? "no data")
    }
    
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Unrelated but `var postData = NSData()` => `var postData = Data()`, that should avoid you all the recast `as NSData`, `as Data`. `request.setValue("text/html", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`, aren't you saying that you are sending `text/html`, instead of `"application/json"`? Also, it's usually `"application/json"`, not `"json/application"`, as I am seeing it in `Accept`.

Comment: I agree, you want `application/json` for both of those headers.